# Clicking on buttons without releasing touch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have 5 buttons in a row:

[image]

I am trying to detect a touch of the user on all the of the buttons without releasing his touch - like touching a piano.

So far I tried this:

```
func buildButtons() {
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchDown)
      view.addSubview(button)
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
      sender.isEnabled = false
      sender.isEnabled = true
      print(sender.tag)
}
```

But what I get is a button that is touched and then when I touch the next one, without releasing, nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue related to multitouch. You can try to enable multitouch of the view.

```
self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but unfortunately it doesn't work on my device nor the simulator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's not working out for you, I've implemented a simple test project and for me touching down the next button without releasing the first one works. Here's the code I've written

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 40.0), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 45)))
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 10

        let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)))
        let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)))
        let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)))

        [button1, button2, button3].forEach { button in
            button.backgroundColor = .blue
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDownAction), for: .touchDown)
        }

        view.addSubview(stackView)
    }

    @objc func touchDownAction() {
        print("touched button")
    }
```

This code was tested on an iphone running ios 11.4. Could you give some additional info?

EDIT: I've updated the solution so that it works when dragging your finger from one button to the next, sorry for my misunderstanding. Hope this works for you. Also keep in mind that now you will have another problem, your touch down action will get called continuously while your finger is inside the button.

```
    var button1: UIButton!
    var button2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 40.0), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 45)))
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 10

        button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)))
        button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)))

        [button1, button2].forEach { button in
            button!.backgroundColor = .blue
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button!)
        }

        view.addSubview(stackView)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: view)
        let button1FrameInMainView = button1.convert(button1.bounds, to: view)
        let button2FrameInMainView = button2.convert(button2.bounds, to: view)

        if button1FrameInMainView.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("touch inside button 1")
        }

        if button2FrameInMainView.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("touch inside button 2")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your help but I just tried your code on my device running iOS 11.3 & xcode simulator and it doesn't work.. it does work when I click with two fingers on it, but not with only one.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something related to the simulator? My test involved putting one finger on the first button, then while still holding that button pressed, I put another finger on the second button.

Comment: There is a misunderstood: I meant putting one finger on the first button, then drag this finger to the second button, then to the third and so on...